# Como executar e capturar a saída de uma linha de comando em C#

Tags: c#, .net, cmd

Pessoa, é o seguinte.
Tenho uma aplicação que funciona em linha de comando. Essa aplicação recebe parâmetros por linha de comando, ex: programa.exe [parametros] Eu quero fazer uma interface onde eu executo essa aplicação passando os comandos e capturo o que a aplicação está exibindo em linha de comando, e mostre isso em uma txtLabel.
A parte de passar os comandos e executar a aplicação eu sei fazer. O que não consigo é capturar o que está saindo em linha de comando e exibir em um Label.

Estava pensando em fazer a aplicação em cmd salvar a saída em .txt e com a interface em c#, ler esse .txt e exibir em tela. Mas creio não ser o ideal.

No meu caso eu estou rodando o youtube-dl e quero capturar a saída dele constantemente e mostrar em um label.

Comment: Seria mais fácil você remover a regra de negócio para outra camada e simplesmente construir a sua nova interface em um novo projeto WindowsForms, Web ou no que desejar.

Comment: Já tentou com a classe `Process`?

Comment: Vou procurar os métodos dela.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu já fiz isto que você está tentando. Basta você executar sua aplicação console através do cmd via C#.
No exemplo abaixo na resposta correta, onde está "command" substitua pela **path + executável da sua aplicação + parâmetros necessários**.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5519328/executing-batch-file-in-c-sharp

Comment: Muito obrigado. Vou testar, verificar se funciona e dou o feedback aqui.

Comment: Por nada! Sucesso!